# Aspose font directory order of search

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I read that there is no guarantee of loading fonts while working with Aspose if we dont't mention explicitely where to search, why is that? and is it better to copy fonts in the 3 main directories that Aspose looks for fonts? or just have them in one directory as `/usr/share/fonts/` 
Thank you in adavance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Linux distributions store fronts in different folders. Aspose.Words looks for fonts in several well-known locations. By default, Aspose.Words looks for the fonts in all of the following locations:

- /usr/share/fonts
- /usr/local/share/fonts
- /usr/X11R6/lib/X11/fonts

This default behavior will work for most Linux distributions, but not guaranteed to work all of the time.

It is not necessary to copy fonts in all directories. You can copy fonts in **any one** of the above three directories. If none of the above directories are present on your Linux then you can [specify a custom font folder](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsjava/True+Type+Fonts#TrueTypeFonts-SpecifyingaFontFolder).

I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: thank you alot for your answer, do you think there is advantages or disadvantages of copying fonts into two or more directories? Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no harm in placing fonts in multiple directories. Upon startup, Aspose.Words will scan these directories and the ones mentioned via FontSettings and then cache the scan results for future use (_e.g. use them during rendering to PDF/XPS/Images etc_).

Comment: thank you for this nice explanation, only one thing it is not clear: upon statrtup means while reading a document maybe? or perhaps while loading the license? thank you

Comment: @KhalilM, I think, it is when the JAR (assembly) of the Aspose.Words for Java API is loaded by JVM.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer!